# finding employees whose location do not contain comma or period or quote charater

Tags: mysql, sql

Can some one tell me how to find 'location' values who do not contain comma or period or quote character in it from table 'Details' in SQL?

Comment: Add some example data and the expacted result

Answer (score 3):

Use `not like` to find them.

```
SELECT *
FROM details
WHERE location not like '%,%'
AND location not like '%.%'
AND location not like '%"%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `not regexp`

```
select *
from details
where location not regexp '.*[,."'].*'
```